# Parse XML file to fetch required data and store it in mongodb database in Python

Tags: python, xml, mongodb, xml-parsing, pymongo

I have an XML file which looks like this:

[XML File](https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/event_search?app_key=USO53E2ZHT6LM4D5RA&country=DE&max=100&date=Future&page=1)

I want to fetch following information from this file for all the events:

Under category event:

- start_date
- end_date
- title

Under category venue:

- address
- address_2/
- city
- latitude
- longitude
- name
- postal_code

and then store this information in a mongodb database. I don't have much experience in parsing. Can someone please help me with this! Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib2 import urlopen

cl = MongoClient()
coll = cl["dbname"]["collectionname"]

tree = ET.parse("https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/event_search?app_key=USO53E2ZHT6LM4D5RA&country=DE&max=100&date=Future&page=1")
root = tree.getroot()

for event in root.findall("./event"):
    doc = {}
    for c in event.getchildren():
        if c.tag in ("start_date", "end_date", "title"):
            doc[c.tag] = c.text
        elif c.tag == "venue":
            doc[c.tag] = {}
            for v in c.getchildren():
                if v.tag in ("address", "address_2", "city", "latitude", "longitude", "name", "postal_code"):
                    doc[c.tag][v.tag] = v.text

    coll.insert(doc)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example that parses an xml from the url using [lxml](http://lxml.de) and inserts the data into mongodb using [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import pymongo
from lxml import etree


# parse xml file
root = etree.parse(urlopen('https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/event_search?app_key=USO53E2ZHT6LM4D5RA&country=DE&max=100&date=Future&page=1'))

events = []
for event in root.xpath('.//event'):
    event = {'start_date': event.find('start_date').text,
             'end_date': event.find('end_date').text,
             'title': event.find('title').text}
    events.append(event)


# insert the date into MongoDB
db = pymongo.MongoClient()
collection = db.test

collection.insert(events)
```

Parsing `venue` items is left for you as a "homework".

Note that there are other xml parsers out there, like:

- [elementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from stdlib
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Hope that helps.